# I'm developing an Android, but I can't see my "console.log" in logcat

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm developing an Android application with Ionic and Capacitor, and I want to debug my code in Android Studio, but I can't see my "console.log" in logcat.

Thank you for your help.

Here's my code:

```
async loadFoldersWithMp3() {
    try {
      const folders = await this.musicScannerService.scanFoldersWithMp3();
      console.log(folders);
      this.foldersWithMp3 = Array.from(folders); // Convertir l'ensemble en tableau
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors du chargement des dossiers", error);
    }
  }
```

Thank you very much! I think I might have a problem in my code. When I run my app, the Logcat shows a list of all folders instead of just the folders containing .mp3 files, as intended.

my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Directory, Filesystem } from '@capacitor/filesystem';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MusicScannerService {
  constructor() { }

  public async scanFoldersWithMp3(directory: string = ''): Promise<string[]> {
    let foldersWithMp3: string[] = [];
    await this.scanDirectory(directory, foldersWithMp3);
    return foldersWithMp3.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index); // Filtrer les doublons
  }

  private async scanDirectory(path: string, foldersWithMp3: string[]): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const result = await Filesystem.readdir({
        directory: Directory.ExternalStorage,
        path: path
      });

      for (const fileName of result.files) {
        const fullPath = path ? `${path}/${fileName}` : fileName;
        const stat = await Filesystem.stat({
          directory: Directory.ExternalStorage,
          path: typeof fullPath === 'string' ? fullPath : fullPath.name
        });

        if (stat.type === 'directory') {
        } else if (typeof fullPath === 'string' && fullPath.endsWith('.mp3')) {
          console.log("Pas Ok");
        } else {
          const fileName = (typeof fullPath === 'string') ? fullPath : fullPath.name;
          if (fileName.endsWith('.mp3')) {
            if (!foldersWithMp3.includes(path)) {
              foldersWithMp3.push(path);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Erreur lors du scan du dossier ${path}:`, error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Device Selection: Ensure that the correct device is selected in Android Studio's logcat to see the logs from the device or emulator where your application is running.

Console Output Configuration: In Capacitor, you can configure console outputs for different environments. Make sure that your "console.log" statements are not suppressed or redirected to a different output in your Capacitor configuration.

Comment: use chrome devtool to see console and debug your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, but with Chrome DevTools, I can't see the Android file system.

Answer (score 3):

1. Please check if you attached the debugger (Click the "bug" icon on
   the toolbar) and select your app
2. Make sure the proper device is selected in Logcat (at the very top of the panel)
3. Make sure you did not filter out your logs (the input field to the right of the device selection in Logcat)
4. Try to restart Logcat by hitting the "Restart Logcat" action[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I might have a problem in my code. When I run my app, the Logcat shows a list of all folders instead of just the folders containing .mp3 files, as intended. (I have modified my code above)